# I am trying to make a performant box fill for highlight

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I am calling the FigureOutBoxFillHighlight function everytime you move your mouse passing in when you started holding down your mouse to when you let go

The BoxFillHighlight function creates a box fill from point "start" to point "end"

The code below should create tiles preformantly as a preview for tiles that will get placed when you let go of your mouse.

The issue is that when passing over the x and y axis in perspective of the "start" position the tiles will misplace and leave floating highlight tiles

```
private void BoxFillHighlight(TileBase tile, Vector3Int start, Vector3Int end)
    {
        //Determine directions on X and Y axis
        var xDir = start.x < end.x ? 1 : -1;
        var yDir = start.y < end.y ? 1 : -1;
        //How many tiles on each axis?
        int xCols = 1 + Mathf.Abs(start.x - end.x);
        int yCols = 1 + Mathf.Abs(start.y - end.y);
        //Start painting
        for (var x = 0; x < xCols; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < yCols; y++)
            {
                var tilePos = start + new Vector3Int(x * xDir, y * yDir, 0);
                highlightTilemap.SetTile(tilePos, tile);
            }
        }
    }
    private void FigureOutBoxFillHighlight(TileBase tile, Vector3Int start, Vector3Int end)
    {
        //Determine directions on X and Y axis
        var xDir = start.x < end.x ? 1 : -1;
        var yDir = start.y < end.y ? 1 : -1;

        if ((end.x - lastHighlightPosition.x) * xDir > 0)
        {
            BoxFillHighlight(tile, new Vector3Int(lastHighlightPosition.x, start.y), end);
        }
        if ((end.x - lastHighlightPosition.x) * xDir < 0)
        {
            BoxFillHighlight(null, new Vector3Int(end.x + xDir, start.y), lastHighlightPosition);
        }
        if ((end.y - lastHighlightPosition.y) * yDir > 0)
        {
            BoxFillHighlight(tile, new Vector3Int(start.x, lastHighlightPosition.y), end);
        }
        if ((end.y - lastHighlightPosition.y) * yDir < 0)
        {
            BoxFillHighlight(null, new Vector3Int(start.x, end.y + yDir), lastHighlightPosition);
        }

        lastHighlightPosition = end;
    }
```

Ive tried fiddling with the x and y offsets and shifting some values by 1 or -1

I am using unity's tilemap system for the tiles